# Can't Install the PHP drivers for Microsoft SQL Server Debian 8

Tags: php, sqlsrv, debian-jessie

I am trying to install PHP drivers for MSSQL Server because I get an error sqlsrv_connect is undefined

I ran the command `sudo pecl install sqlsrv`

and I get this error output:

```
Makefile:181: recipe for target 'conn.lo' failed
make: *** [conn.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

I can't seem to find what is going on wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out the solution to this:
The problem was I didn't have php-pear php7.2-dev
so running the following command:

`sudo apt-get install php-pear php7.2-dev`

Then proceed with: `sudo pecl install sqlsrv`

That worked!